# AWS IoT: When to use thing attribute over Shadow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I saw that there was an question already, but I receive a page not found error when accessing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284026/aws-iot-thing-attrubite-vs-shadow-property?S_TACT=

So I've got the same question.
I've got some fields which could definitely be an attribute as they're not changing: `DeviceId`, `SerialNumber` and some others.

But I also want to store/update :

- rather seldomly updated fields: e.g. the `status` from (Created -> Registered -> Unregistered)
- frequently updated fields: e.g. `lastSeen` timestamp when the last message was sent

Should I now use Device Shadow for everything, Thing Attributes for everything or mix it?